# Simple random walk on the vertices of a cube

Tags: probability, markov-chains, conditional-expectation, random-walk

Here I am considering a simple random walk on the vertices of a cube: at each time, an ant jumps from one vertex to one of its neighbours, each with probably 1/3.

$v_0$ is a fixed vertex of the cube and the chain also starts here. We let $T_{v_0} = min\{n\geq 1 : X_n = v_0\}$ and $\mathbb{E}[T_{v_0} | X_0 = v_i] = m_i $

My goal here is to show:

> for $i\neq0$ $$\mathbb{E}[T_{v_0}|X_1=v_i] = m_i + 1 $$

However, I don't know really where to start here. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you double check your expression for $T_{v_0}$, are you sure it doesn't say $X_n = v_0$ on the right.

Comment: I think that with your definition of $T_{v_0}$ it would hold that: $$\mathbb{E}[T_{v_0}| X_1=v_i] =1.$$ do you see the problem?

Comment: Why exactly would that equal 1 ?

Comment: You write “$v_0$ is fixed.. and the chain also starts here” but then you mentioned $E(T_{v_0} | X_0=v_i)$ which says you start at the vertex $v_i$ for some $i$—well, which is it?